# Gap between the border and the nine patch background of a list element (LinearLayout)

Tags: android, listview, nine-patch

I use a ListView with different "styled" component. The first and the second component from the picture use a programmatically drawn background. 
The third and the fourth element has a nine-patch background. 
When I click on a element the selector from the ListView colorize and covers the selected element.

My problem is know that I have a gap between border and nine-patch background. Give it any solution to eliminate this gap?

[Screenshot with selected second list element (programmatically background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WY8f.jpg)

[Screenshot with selected fourth list element (nine-patch background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpK1f.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found for me a solution. I remove all selector states from the ListView (setSelector(new StateListDrawable())) and add a OnTouchListener to the ListView.

The OnTouchListener trigger to different methods to set or delete a ColorFilter on the drawn background from the view element. The ColorFilter places only over the painted (nine-patch or programmatically background) area and not over the gap.

```
public class ClickAndReleaseListener implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    /**
     * Activity with integrated Adapter (from ListView) to do the triggered methods
     */
    public IClickAndReleaseListener releaseListener;

    /**
     * Call from Activity (with the ListView) ex. listView.setOnTouchListener(new ClickAndReleaseListener(Activity.this))
     * @param releaseListener => Activity with implemented Interface
     */
    public ClickAndReleaseListener(IClickAndReleaseListener releaseListener)
    {
        this.releaseListener = releaseListener;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //Aenderung der Visualisierung für das angeklickte Element.
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //method find the triggered element and set a ColorFilter at the drawable background
                //ex. visibleElement.getBackground().setColorFilter(ColorSpace.getHighlightColorFilter)
                releaseListener.setColorFilter(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //method iterate to all elements and set a null ColorFilter at the drawable background
                releaseListener.releaseColorFilter();
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```